# is it not a good practice to have a class without final fields in Dart?

Tags: dart, class, field, flutter-getx

I have this situation where I want to make classes reactive, I will use GetX lib for the example.

I have this User class.

```
class User {
    User({
        required this.id,
        required this.name,
    });

    int id;
    String name;

    factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
    };
}
```

I will make that class reactive.

```
final Rx<User> user = User(1, "Test");
```

Fields cannot be final because I might need to reassign them and rebuild certain widget, for example.

```
user.value.name = "Test2";
user.refresh(); // This will trigger rebuild widget.
```

If I had final fields in the class I would need to have separate reactive fields to each field I need to update and rebuild widgets:

```
final RxInt id = 0.obs;
final RxString name = "Test".obs

id.value = 1; // This would trigger rebuild widget.
name.value = "Test2"; // This would trigger rebuild widget.
```

Let's say I have like 20 fields or more would be easier to not have final fields, is it not a good practice creating classes like this?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier, but you should understand that all of your .obs like vars are stream-like, which isn't optimized, but very easy to use and understand.
I use in project immutable-like objects because it's more obvious than variable mutations, and as a plus, I can save all of the class states because all changes its other class instance.

The immutable and mutable ways are different, so one is better then other in some cases or for some architecture, as well as the second.

You can read about https://bloclibrary.dev/ and https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/state_management.md. Its two different ways to build arch and you can create own conclusions for you question